# Embedding videos via open gragh tags on Facebook does not play

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, video-embedding

I have the following og tags for videos to be posted and played on Facebook, however the video plays only in 'HTTP' mode and not in 'HTTPS'. This is run on PHPmotion script and player. These are the tags added in the main_1.htm file.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="[var.page_title;htmlconv=no;]" />
<meta property="og:description" content="[var.description;htmlconv=no;]" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="[var.base_url]/videos/[var.vid]/[var.title_seo]"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="[var.base_url]/uploads/player_thumbs/[var.video_thumb]" />

<meta property="og:video" content="[var.base_url]/player.swf?flvsource=[var.base_url]/uploads/[var.video_play]&preview_image=[var.base_url]/uploads/player_thumbs/[var.video_thumb]&backgcolor=FFFFFF&autoplay=true&url_logo=[var.base_url]/images/playerlogos/logo-player.png&logo=top_right&floating_navbar=false&color_nav_bar_top=0x478dc2&color_nav_bar_bottom=0xE7EBEC&ads_background_color=0x00CCFF&ads_border_color=0xCCCCCC&scrubber_position_color=0x6AA1CE&scrubber_load_color=0x888888&scrubber_background_color=0xBBBBBB&volume_bar_color=0xBBBBBB&aspect_ratio=stretch" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="560" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="420" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

**Note:** Just because the video is in HTTP doesn't mean HTTP videos won't run in HTTPS on Facebook because—videos in HTTP by YouTube runs properly even when browsing with HTTPS on Facebook, so what could be the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have facing the same problem months ago. Facebook mentions that https is required for the embedding.

Youtube (and a few other sites) are whitelisted by them